# Correlation ID for logs in Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently developing a Node based solution which is hosted using Firebase functions. When I log something out, I'm wanting to include some kind of correlation ID so I can accurately trace a request as it moves through the system. In the case of an HTTP endpoint, I can use the Express framework, as there are many libraries which handle exactly this type of concern.

However, in the case of a consumer which consumes from a Pub/Sub topic, I can't use the same solution. Is there an elegant way of creating some kind of request-scoped context which can store some correlation ID and be used when creating my logs?

Comment: For PubSub, I guess the only thing that could make sense for your case is logging the `event_id` located inside the `context` of that request, would that work for what you are trying to do?

Comment: @RafaelLemos it would work but the my PubSub consumer has multiple dependencies being instantiated. I don't want to pass the `event_id` along into each dependency as that's messy and becomes unmaintainable. Looking for a way to just set it to a request scoped context to be accessible in the logger factory to decorate the stream.

Comment: to be clear, what do you mean by multiple dependencies? eg. multiple functions, multiple topics, multiple products inside GCP. TBH since you would need something that propagates through different gcp products I would say that you would either have to use the existing IDs, or manage all that by creating an extra parameter being sent by the event trigger of your pubsub topic.

Comment: Managed to solve my problem with async_hooks and creating a context which can be accessed from anywhere within the scope of the function. Will post the solution as an answer shortly.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-hooks-context
Wrapping my PubSub function handlers, or onCall handlers with the correlation ID function solved my problems.

Comment: Could you post the solution you found with more details (a sample perhaps) as an answer?